# AX=XB and the Cecioni--Frobenius theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

The Frobenius--Cecioni theorem states that if $A$ and $B$ are square matrices with entries in a field $k$ then the dimension of the $k$ vector space of solutions of
$$
AX=XB
$$
is given by the sum
$$
\sum_{i,j} \deg( \gcd(d_i(A),d_j(B)))
$$
Here $d_i(\cdot)$ denotes the $i$th invariant factor of its argument. My question: How well known is this theorem in any particular context? (E.g., "I use it all the time and I work in number theory ...", "I've never heard of it and I taught abstract algebra for years ...") Are there any well known applications of this result?

Answer (score 6):

Great, so now I know how it is called. I came across a corollary some time ago (C. Koc, AMM 2002, solution of problem #10813) and posted it [on the MathLinks forum](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?t=256194). From this corollary either "loup blanc" (another poster in that topic) or me reconstructed the theorem, at least in the case of an algebraically closed field.

I still do not know an answer to the natural question: For a given $n$, what are the possible values of $m$ such that there exist two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ with $\dim\left\lbrace X\in k^{n\times n}\mid AX=XB\right\rbrace = m$ ? This is equivalent to asking for the possible values of $\sum\limits_{i} a_ib_i$ where $\left(a_i\right)$ and $\left(b_i\right)$ are two finite sequences of nonnegative integers satisfying $\sum\limits_i a_i\leq n$ and $\sum\limits_i b_i\leq n$. This is a purely combinatorial question. Maybe you happen to know an answer to it, since I am hardly the first person to pose it?...